# `window.location.href` not working as intended

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm using a JavaScript, along with PHP, to create a login system for a project I'm working on.

I have everything working in regards to actually logging the user in, and then checking this within my JavaScript. However when I redirect the user from the login page to a private page, I'm having issues with `window.location.href` in the JavaScript.

I own the domain thomas-smyth.co.uk, so I have tried the following piece of code to redirect the user.

```
window.location.href = "http://thomas-smyth.co.uk/home.php";
```

However, when this redirects me, it is redirecting me to thomas.smyth.co.uk, which obviously causes the page not to load. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: You should never write an authentication system in javascript. It's client side and you can't trust it.

Comment: You're sure `home.php` isn't doing a header redirect?

Comment: your whole webserver directory is reachable by internet you should fix this. You have to remove the "www" part in your url.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm with you. JS should not really do anything but what you tell it to when changing location. If you end up in a different place, it's most likely that you got redirected by the server. To verify, go to the browser, open developer tools, go to the network tab and make sure the log is persisted, then navigate to the page. You will get all the network requests and what they contained.

Comment: Just to elaborate on what Ben said, if you do client-side authentication, all the user has to do is open the browser console, and they can manually bypass anything they want once they get a feel for your code.

Comment: and you can see javascript at anytime because the browser downloads it.

Comment: @vlaz Only thing that makes sense. I haven't written JS in awhile, but I wouldn't expect it to drop part of the directory for some reason.

Comment: Did you try escaping the hypen like this, /-.

Comment: All the authentication is done in PHP. The JavaScript simply calls the php file when the login button is clicked, that creates the login session and then if a value is echoed by that file then the Javascript redirects you to a page that will have another login check. The Javascript handles no authentication of login. I haven't put www on my url and doing /- does not work either.

Comment: in this file http://thomas-smyth.co.uk/functions/login.js

Comment: is this `window.location.href = "http://www.thomas.smyth.co.uk/home.php";` like I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have posted the wrong code. In your Js File [thomas-smyth.co.uk/functions/login.js](http://thomas-smyth.co.uk/functions/login.js)  on your webserver is this:

```
//Re-directs to subdomain.
window.location.href = "http://www.thomas.smyth.co.uk/home.php";
```

this should be fixed to

```
//Re-directs to subdomain.
window.location.href = "http://thomas-smyth.co.uk/home.php";
```

@vlaz mentioned right, you have a second mistake with a wrong dot instead of a dash

And btw you should explain your problem a bit more. More code would be usefull next time if you want some help.

Comment: Shouldn't the corrected one point to `thomas-smyth` with a dash rather than dot?

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. I have re-uploaded my file several times with thomas-smyth, in fact I can never remember it being that at all and I've hard refreshed (Ctrl+Shift+R), but it doesn't update.

Comment: It seems the file has updated now, issue resolved. Thanks!